# I need to dispatch action inside a saga by looping through an array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

What I want to achieve is to loop through and array with an interval (`setTimeout`) and dispatch action sequentially.
Below is my code:

```
        yield responses.forEach(response => {
            setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log(response);
                put(addResponseToConversation(response));
            }, 200)
        });
```

It doesn't work unfortunately. What is it that I am missing?

Comment: yield should be before put also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.forEach()` won't wait for one timer to expire and dispatch an action before setting up a new timer. It will just iterate over the array and set up multiple timers.

What you need is a way to wait for one action to be dispatched before dispatching another action. For this, you could create a function, lets name it "sleep", that returns a `Promise` which is fulfilled after specific amount of time. Using a `for of` loop, you could dispatch an action and then wait for the `Promise` from "sleep" function to resolve before dispatching another action.

"sleep" function should look like this:

```
function sleep(seconds) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000);
   });
}
```

Within your saga, use `for of` loop to iterate over the array, dispatch an action and then call `sleep` function to add a delay between each action.

```
for (let res of responses) {
    yield put(addResponseToConversation(res));
    yield call(sleep, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Now I get it, I had to switch from ```forEach``` to the classical ```for ... of ...```. I guess I got too carried away with ES6!   ':D